# Writing R dataframe into AzureSQL DB from Azure Databricks notebook

Tags: r, azure-sql-database, rodbc, azure-databricks

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL DB from R notebook on Azure Databricks. I am getting the following error:

`first argument is not an open RODBC channel
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:########.database.windows.net,1433;Database=########;Uid=####@#######;Pwd=#########;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:########.database.windows.net,1433;Database=########;Uid=####@#######;Pwd=#########;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;") :
  ODBC connection failed`

This is my connetion string:

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQLServer};Server=tcp:########.database.windows.net,1433;Database=########;Uid=#### 
@#######;Pwd=#########;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection 
Timeout=30;")

Query - res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'SELECT * FROM table_name') `
```

Could someone tell me where the problem is. Or some possible alternative which I can use to write a dataframe to Azure SQL DB from Azure Databricks notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the ODBC driver before setting up the connection, as Azure Databricks itself does not contain one.

Run below shell script in a separate cell together as a chunk to install the driver:

```
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Databricks R notebook

```
library(SparkR)

#replace<..> with your connection strings
Conn <- "jdbc:sqlserver://<myserver>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<mydatabase>;user=<database_user>;password=<password>"

#Convert a R dataframe to a Spark dataframe
df <- as.DataFrame(df)

write.jdbc(df, Conn, "SQLtablename", mode = "overwrite")
```

Comment: Can we execute CREATE or UPDATE statements the same way?